# How to get a DLR representation from C#?

Tags: c#, ironpython, ironruby, dynamic-language-runtime

Is there a generic method of converting a Dynamic Language Runtime (DLR) object into a string representation? For example, here is an example where obj is checked for a couple of specific types (Python, in this case):

```
        if (obj is IronPython.Runtime.List) {
          repr = ((IronPython.Runtime.List)obj).__repr__(
                  IronPython.Runtime.DefaultContext.Default);
        } else if (obj is IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary) {
          repr = ((IronPython.Runtime.PythonDictionary)obj).__repr__(
                  IronPython.Runtime.DefaultContext.Default);
```

But I would really like to get a representation of obj in its own language (IronPython, IronRuby, etc) and without having to compare to each and every type. obj.ToString() doesn't give a good representation for most objects.

Comment: Well you could get one representation per language (__repr__ if it exists to_s if it exists then ToString otherwise) but there is no specific way. The best you could do is have a list of language-equivalent "ToString" and check for all of them. But you don't need as in your example to manage each object type separately.

Comment: Good, that does work for IronPython objects: they all seem to have a "__repr__" method in C#. But it doesn't seem that IronRuby objects have a "to_s" method at the C# level.

Comment: I can't see why as it's on the `Object` class ( http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-to_s ) i don't do much ruby or python, but what I know tell me that every ruby object should expose a `to_s` method. Also the equivalent of `__repr__` is supposed to be `inspect` ( http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-inspect ) while `to_s` is supposed to be an equivalent of `__str__` in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no one common method to convert DLR objects to their representative string representations.  It is language dependent and they are not implemented the same unfortunately.

With IronPython at least, you could always just get a reference to the Builtin module then call the `str()` (or `repr()`) function on your objects.

```
var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
dynamic obj = engine.Execute("[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]");
dynamic builtin = engine.GetBuiltinModule();
string repr = builtin.str(obj);
```

Of course you could call the function within the script too.

```
string repr = (string)engine.Execute("str([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])");
```

Another option would be to use one of the many operations defined in the `IronPython.Runtime.Operations` namespace.

```
string repr = IronPython.Runtime.Operations.PythonOps.ToString(obj);
```

I'm not very familiar with IronRuby but calling `to_s()` on some objects seems to work sometimes.  Otherwise, it actually returns a .NET object where `to_s` does not exist and is not very reliable.  I think it's easier to do it within the script.

```
var engine = Ruby.CreateEngine();
string repr = (string)engine.Execute("[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].to_s");
```

You might want to look around and see if there are other methods you could use.

Comment: Part of my problem is that these are stand-alone objects, and I don't know what language they have come from. The task is to go through a shared ScriptScope which is language neutral, but show the objects as they appear in the host language (or in some generic representation). I used VirtualBlackFox's suggestion to look for a method ___repr___ method, and that works for IronPython, but I can't find anything on the IronRuby methods. Nor would I have a way to do this for future DLR languages. Perhaps a ToRepr() method should be added to the base object in all languages.